# iPad pro can’t “see” magic mouse 2

Tags: ipad, mouse

I used to work with magic mouse 2 on my iPad Pro v13, but since the latest update 13.3, now the mouse is not even discoverable via Bluetooth.

I tried everything from resetting network, to hard rebooting, on/off, mouse, accessibility, not even discoverable in switches and so... The mouse is working just fine on other devices, but the iPad pro... any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) The current latest public version of iPadOS is 13.2.3. Are you running a beta version of iPadOS?

Comment: It only shows 13.3 version. Used to download the beta profile way back the summer. Do you think that can be the problem? Should I delete the beta profile? Thanks

Comment: You should consider deleting the beta profile if you wish to run the production/public version of iPadOS. It's possible Apple "may" have either removed the support for Bluetooth mouse or it's buggy in iPadOS 13.3.